# How to align icon and nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes, altacv

I'm relatively new to LaTeX. I want to vertically align an icon and few nodes. Also, I want the text inside them to be centered.

Here is my code-

```
\small\faCalendar~\forcsvlist{\makenodes}{x,X,x,y}
    
\newcommand{\makenodes}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex, text height=0.75ex,text depth=.125ex, font=\tiny]{#1};
}
```

This is the output I got -

[image: Output]

You can see the icon and the nodes are not aligned. If I don't use fixed `text height` and fixed `text depth` the rectangles differ in heights.

How can I align these? And, is there any way to achieve this without using fixed `text height` and fixed `text depth`?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (1) Reduce `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`. (2) Choose a smaller font for the letters: `{\small #1}` or `{\footnotesize #1}`  If you want us to give more specific help, please provide a complete small document producing your last picture.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `yshift` in the node properties did the trick. This is the output I was looking for.

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
logotip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base),
node distance = 0pt and 1em,
     N/.style = {draw=gray, semithick, rounded corners, 
                 text height=1.75ex, text depth=.25ex, anchor=base,
                 font=\small}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N]{x};
\node (n2) [N,right=of n1]{X};
\node (n3) [N,right=of n2]{x};
\node (n4) [N,right=of n3]{y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If you like to have smaller node size and font, see if scaling of node gives desired result. For example:

```
     N/.style = {draw=gray, semithick, rounded corners=2pt,
                 text height=1.76ex, text depth=.25ex, anchor=base,
                 font = \small,
                 scale=0.8} % select value
```

at `scale=0.5`:

[image]

at `scale=0.8`:

[image]

Comment: I want to reduce the height of the rectangles. And, I preferably want to use `font=\tiny`. What is the correct `text height` and `text depth` for this font if I want to center it inside the box?

Comment: @iqHpi, just try this in see, if result is closer to what you like to have . With reducing font size you also need to reduce node size accordingly, or scale node size:. See edited answer.